# Translate VHDL to Verilog : instanciate specific nets of a bus to a component input

Tags: verilog

I'm translating a VHDL code into Verilog. Does someone know hos to translate this one?

VHDL code:

```
U1 : CORRECTION
  port map(
       CONFIG => CONFIG,
       MAC(0) => MAC(0),
       MAC(1) => MAC(1),
       MODD => MODD,
```

I tried this in Verilog but...

```
CORRECTION U1 (
       .CONFIG (CONFIG),
       .PWM (PWM),
       .MAC (MAC),
//       .MAC[0] (MAC[0]),
//       .MAC[1] (MAC[1]),
       .MODD (MODD),
```

Comment: From what I think you are trying to do, it looks correct. What problems specifically are you running into (compiler error/simulation errors)?

Comment: what I wanted to do is commented. I want to connect a part of the bus to the component input (I. e. the bus at top level is 8 bits and the component input is 3 bits).

Comment: There is no way to connect to a part of a bus like that (ie, `MAC` looks something like `input [1:0] MAC`, you cannot connect to just one bit of `MAC`, you can only connect to all of `MAC` or none of it). You can however connect a wire to all of `MAC` and then piece-wise assign it.

Answer (score 0):

Commenter correctly pointed out that you cannot connect only part of a port in verilog, however you can use a concatenation of signals to connect to the port.

If your MAC input is declared as

input [1:0] MAC,

you can connect to it in the instance by using

.MAC (MAC[1:0]),

or

.MAC ({MAC[1], MAC[0]}),

which would then work if the top level MAC signal was larger than 2.